# Integration tests create files for the packaged jar

Tags: maven, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I'm generating spring-restdocs snippets with rest assured in my integration tests.
With maven and the failsafe plugin that defaults to the `integration-test` and `verify` phase. Problem is, that `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` (to generate the final HTML file out of the snippets) and `maven-resources-plugin` (to copy the final HTML file into the correct place) run before the integration tests in `prepare-package`.

With that asciidoctor naturally fails, because the snippets are not generated yet.

If I configure asciidoctor to run at `post-integration-test`, it succeeds, but then the finished HTML page is not in my jar, cause the jar was already created in the `package` phase.

So I feel like the only option is to run my integration tests already in the `tests` phase (probably with surefire instead of failsafe).

I could also split out the Documentation related tests from the rest of the integration tests, but I actually like to have them in the seemingly correct place.

I wonder if there is a best practice I'm ignoring?
Should integration tests never produce something to put inside the jar?

It looks to me, that integration tests in maven are meant for cross-jar tests (hence running them after package). And not like I'm using them, just for *bigger* tests that involve multiple parts (especially DB) all within one jar.

What I would like:

1. run all tests
2. compile documentation
3. package everything into the jar

Excerpt from my `pom.xml`

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skipSurefire}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                        <include>**/*E2ET.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Compile API documentation -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Package API documentation -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/public/docs
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                    </directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

The phases `integration-test` and `verify` are just the *default* bindings of the [integration-test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) and the [verify](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html) goal. You can bind your integration tests to the `test` phase, as well:

```xml
                  ...
                  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                  ...
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
```

and such achieve the order you like/need.